# Shinobi SChartScatterSeries z-order

Tags: ios, shinobi

I have more than one `SChartScatterSeries` on my graph, I would like to change the z-order of series when user selects a point in order to move the selected series on the foreground.

Otherwise when users selects a point, it is hidden by other series.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to set the z-order of the series, is the order in which they are presented to the datasource.

You could use the delegate method for selection events to trigger a reload and then a redraw -with the ordering you would like. This should be fast enough that it is not noticeable in the majority of cases. Don't forget to mark the series as selected when you re-pass it to the datasource to maintain the correct state.

Comment: I have a very large dataset (> 50K points) and it's filtered by 3 criteria that have, say, 10 options each. Datasource reload was to slow when filter was changed, so I represent the dataset with 3x10 different scatter series that I show/hide as the filter. Moving back to reload would slow app again.